# Python or Lua - Realtime application

Tags: python, lua

I have started using **Python** in a real-time application *(serial communication with to gps modules at once)*, but have found out recently about **Lua**. Which language would be more suited to the application?

My definition of real-time in this context is *the fastest possible time to receive, process and output the data.* (Feedback system)

Comment: Obviously that depends on what you're building. Which you hardly mention.

Comment: By "realtime" do you really mean "realtime" where you will be spec'ing out hard requirements for how many milliseconds each operation can take, and which operations absolutely pre-empt which other ones? Because if you really mean "realtime" then you probably cannot use either language. And if you mean something else, you should outline that for us in more detail.

Comment: Sorry I should of been more specific....I am making some code for a GPS tracking system in which two GPS Units input data into the system (code) which is then proccessed and outputed to two servos...

Comment: @Brandon ...By realtime I mean realtime GPS input and proccessing to outputing....understand :)?

Comment: @JamesDyson Nothing in the description says "realtime". I don't :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are fine languages. Neither should take you years to learn. An easy way to make the decision is to look at what modules are out there already.

For example, you mentioned that your application is related to GPS. Take a look at what libraries are already written to hook Python and Lua into your particular GPS hardware. Maybe someone's already done most of the hard work for you. If not, then go down a step. If you're talking to your GPS over an I2C link, look at I2C libraries in both languages. See which ones are more popular and better maintained.

That said, garbage collected languages have historically had problems with meeting real time requirements. Depending on yours, you may need to go with a lower level language. You should also ensure that whatever system you're running on will support your programming environment. I've worked with systems where Python would have been great but it doesn't fit in 5K of code space.

Comment: Garbage collection also makes your program need more memory temporarily (until the garbage collector releases the unused memory). This might be a problem on a system with little memory. In that case, reference counting helps, because it lets the program release memory earlier. Python has combined reference counting and garbage collection, Lua has only garbage collection. Some other scripting languages which support reference counting: Perl, PHP and TCL.

Comment: @pts: Lua has real good record in embedded systems world. Python, on to the other hand, does not.

Comment: @Alexander Gladysh: Except to [control giant robots](http://blip.tv/file/3837633) ;-)

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: I've got an impression that pts talked about little systems with little memory. I assume that giant robots would have literally tons of it! :-)

Comment: Lua has *incremental* garbage collection, which performs well without hiccups.

Comment: @Alexander Gladysh: In my comment I was focusing on the difference between memory management models. This is completely unrelated to which language has which track record, so I don't understand why you addressed your comment to me.

Comment: @pts: It is an empirical indication of the fact that Lua's incremental garbage collector works better on "systems with little memory" than Python's combined one. Don't have any hard data on hands, so I will not start a holy war here :-)

Comment: You can learn the basics of either in a day and get lots of useful work done in a week if you can program. The same applies to most programming languages. I found python (and Ruby) particularly quick, though.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [eLua](http://www.eluaproject.net/) and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Cheers, I am looking into it now :)